# Access C: Drive in Ubuntu after wubi install

Tags: wubi

I use ubuntu for downloading and I want to move the files to my C: Drive so that when I run windows I can access the files. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

your C:/ drive should show at the bottem of the sidebar along with any USB storage devices/ HDDS.  It may be listed as SGxxxxxxxxxxxx or WDxxxxxxxxxxxx (seagate or western digital)